# LTspice simulation of microphone preamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, simulation, microphone, preamp

Can someone help an idiot understand why this plot has dual traces?

The node is between C2 and R7. I have replaced an electret microphone with an AC source.

I don't know how accurate this is, so any tips and ideas are welcome.

In the schematic, I currently have a 0.22uF capacitor on the input to get a high pass filter.

[image]

Comment: It will absolutely not hurt you to press `F1` and read the introductory part of the official help. It may terse at times, but it has plenty of information, including this one. Think of all the time you will avoid wasting: instead of posting an question and waiting hours or possibly more, you would have all the answers readily available. It would also help you better understand the tool that you are about to use.

Comment: For 20 years ago I studied electrical engineering, I had to drop out due to depression and concentration problems, these have gotten worse over time and I simply can not read larger volumes of text. My interest in electronics remain although a lot weaker than it used to be. But thanks for your "concern".

Comment: If you think my message was "rtfm" then you misunderstood (your usage of quotes seems to hint sarcasm, maybe I'm wrong). In fact, if you say you dislike large volumes of text then the help is for you since, as I said, it is terse (sometimes too spartan, I'd say). And yet it has the information that you need (the reason you asked this question). Which is as expected, since that's the purpose of the help. And if reading that doesn't help you, or even help you help yourself (i.e. self-reliant), I don't know what to say, except a neutral "good luck" (or a non-concerned wish, if you will).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Bode plot - one graph is the gain/attenuation and the other is the phase shift.